# MPI implementation to verify

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to use MPI_Gather to recover data from slave. So basically, a simulation are running on each slave (wich is not the same on each), and I want to recover one integer  on the master (the results of the simulation). From each integer, I calculate a new value 'a' on the master that I send back to the slave to redo a new simulation with this better parameter.
I hope is is clear, I am pretty new to MPI.

Note: Some simulation will not finish at the same time.

```
int main
while(true){
if (rank==0) runMaster();
else runSlave();
}

runMaster()
receive data b of all slave (with MPI_gather)
calculate parameter a for each slave; aTotal=[a_1,...,a_n]
MPI_Scatter(aTotal, to slave)

runSlave()
a=aTotal[rank]
simulationRun(a){return b}
MPI_Gather(&b, to master)
```

To avoid the deadlock, each slave is initialized with a random a.

created a small test case, because I don't see how I can use MPI_Gather in my slave:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int size;
int rank;
int a[12];
int i;
int start,end;
int b;


MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Request req;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
int* bb= new int[size];
int source;

//master
if(!rank){
    while(true){
        b=12;
        MPI_Recv(&bb[0], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        source = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        printf("master receive b %d from source %d \n", bb[0], source);
        if (source == 1) goto finish;
    }
}

//slave
if(rank){·
    b=13;·
    if (rank==1) {b=15;  sleep(2);}
    int source = rank;
    printf("slave %d will send b %d \n", source, b);
    // MPI_Gather(&b,1,MPI_INT,bb,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); // unworking, not called by master
    MPI_Send(&b, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
finish:
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to send the slave data to the master with a collective command.

Is this implementation realistic?

Comment: You should post some source code.

Comment: I edited my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you propose sounds reasonable.  Another approach would be to have the slaves all broadcast their results to each other in one go (MPI_AllGather), then you can implement the scoring and what-to-try-next algorithm directly in each slave.  If the scoring algorithm is not too complex, the overhead of running it in every slave will be worth it in terms of speed because the slaves will not have to communicate with the master at all, saving one communication on each iteration.

Comment: OK, thank you for the review. I forgot to mention that the calculation of the new a for each slave is based on all slave results b. [a1,a2]->[b1,b2]->algo->[a1',a2']... Another thing, I just read that MPI_Gather should be call by everyone, but in my case, it will not be called by the master, it will induces an issue?

Comment: Everyone needs to call Gather, but the master can just send bogus data and ignore it.  It won't of course actually send this data on the network anyway, since the destination is itself.

Comment: ok, so i will  probably use your idea, because in my first post, my MPI_Gather in the slave will not work...